# Set timeout with Swagger-JS?

Tags: ajax, swagger

I'm using [Offline.js](https://github.com/hubspot/offline) to handle internet connection issues and recovery from going offline.  However, the default timeout for Ajax calls is <strike>upwards of a minute</strike> [unlimited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#xmlhttprequest-timeout).  How can I change the timeout setting?

Comment: one minute??? are you doing this from a browser or server?

Comment: It might actually be network issue that is specific to my setup, but I need to be able to set the timeout for the call to be sure.